# Sobolev space interpolation

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, interpolation-theory

We are attempting to show that, for $t_0,t_1\in\mathbb{R}$, and $t_\sigma=(1-\sigma)t_0+\sigma t_1$ for any $\sigma\in[0,1]$, then the following inequality holds for any $u\in H^{t_1}(\mathbb{R}^d)$:

$\|u\|_{H^{t_\sigma}(\mathbb{R}^d)}\leq\|u\|^{1-\sigma}_{H^{t_0}(\mathbb{R}^d)}\cdot \|u\|^\sigma_{H^{t_1}(\mathbb{R}^d)}$

A hint given to us was to write the LHS as a Fourier transform, but we do not see how to go about doing that nor how that would help. Any assistance in this area would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

We have, by definition of $H^{t_\sigma}(\def\R{\mathbf R}\R^d)$, that
$$ \def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\def\F{\mathscr F} 
  \norm{u}_{H^{t_\sigma}} = \norm{ (1 + \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs\cdot^2)^{t_\sigma/2}\F u}_{L^2} $$
We have for $\frac 1\alpha + \frac 1\beta = \frac 12$ by Hölder
\begin{align*}
    \norm{u}_{H^{t_\sigma}} &= \norm{ (1 + \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs\cdot^2)^{t_\sigma/2}\F u}_{L^2}\\ 
     &= \norm{\def\f{(1+\abs\cdot^2)}\abs{\f^{t_0/2}}^{1-\sigma}\abs{\F u}^{1-\sigma} \cdot \abs{\f^{t_1/2}}^\sigma\abs{\F u}^\sigma}_{L^2}\\
     &\le \norm{\abs{\f^{t_0/2} \F u}^{1-\sigma}}_\alpha \norm{\abs{\f^{t_1/2}\F u}^{\sigma}}_\beta
\end{align*}
We want the first term to be $\norm{u}_{H^{t_0}}$, that is, $\alpha = \frac{2}{1-\sigma}$, then 
$$ \beta = \frac 1{\frac 12 - \frac 1\alpha} = \frac 1{\frac \sigma 2} = \frac 2\sigma $$
so we have
\begin{align*}
\norm{u}_{H^{t_\sigma}} &\le \norm{\abs{\f^{t_0/2} \F u}^{1-\sigma}}_\alpha \norm{\abs{\f^{t_1/2}\F u}^{\sigma}}_\beta\\
   &= \norm{\f^{t_0/2} \F u}_{L^2}^{1-\sigma} \norm{\f^{t_1/2}\F u}_{L^2}^{\sigma}\\
   &= \norm{u}_{H^{t_0}}^{1-\sigma}\norm{u}_{H^{t_1}}^\sigma
\end{align*}

Comment: Is there a source you could cite for the first norm equality? We have not seen this before...

Comment: How did you define the norm of $H^s(\mathbf R^d)$ then?

Comment: It was defined as: $\|u\|_{H^{s}(\Omega)}^{2}=\|u\|_{H^{m}(\Omega)}^{2}+\sum_{\alpha"|\alpha|=m}\int_{\Omega\times\Omega}\frac{|\partial^{\alpha}u(x)-\partial^{\alpha}u(y)|^{2}}{|x-y|^{2\sigma+d}}dxdy$ where $s=m+\sigma$ with $m$ a positive integer and $\sigma\in[0,1)$

Comment: The $\in t$ above should be $\int$...the site wouldn't let me edit it again...